# Auto respond to prompts in Command line

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to push to git from local. After the `git push origin master` command, it asks for username and password, want to auto fill the username and password. I saw something like `echo Y | command` but it doesn't work for me, just prints the line as it is.

**EDIT 1**

I tried the command, still the same
Here is the file
`F:
cd F:\workspace\APWorkspace\Project
git add .
git commit -m "Auto Backup"
git push origin master
echo abhay93 | git push origin master
pause`
Still it asks for username and then prints `echo abhay93 | git push origin master`

Comment: If your program reads from StdIn then `echo name | git push origin master`

Comment: Write `echo abhay93|git push origin master` instead as the space between `abhay93` and `|` is echoed also otherwise...